# javascript : how to replace symbol with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

how to remove the symbols such as ▼, >>,<< and others using the regex in javascript?

Comment: You really need to accept more answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the replace function for this, specifying the empty string as the replacement string. Here are a couple examples.

If you only want to strip specific characters:

```
s = s.replace(/[▼><]/g, '');
```

Or using a Unicode escape sequence:

```
s = s.replace(/[\u25bc><]/g, '');
```

If you want to strip all but alphanumeric characters:

```
s = s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/, '');
```

**Edit**: described Unicode escape sequence usage.

Comment: if i want to replace any symbol which possible appear in the browser,how i remove it?

Comment: @user495688: But all these characters appear on your browser.

Comment: i have remove all character   var emailPattern = /[_a-zA-Z0-9\.]+@[^\.a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+/gi;
  var urlPattern = /[a-z]+:\/\/[^\s]+/gi;
  var numberOrSymbolPattern = /[^0-9\.,!@#\$%\^\&*\(\)`~_\-=\+|\\{}\[\]\s:;<>\?\/]+/gi; but when i testing my application there are some symbol which can't remove

Answer (score 1):

I'd remove non-standard character(s) by using the unicode token \u and the corresponding character code.

For example:

```
// Remove "▼" using its character code
var s = "I like milk ▼.".replace(/\u9660/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace(/[\u0100-\uffff]/g, '')` to remove characters outside the extended ASCII range.

E.g.

```
>>> "I ȮʼṮ　like ȖŋŀℭỚỄ　Regexs‽‽‽".replace(/[\u0080-\uffff]/g, '')    
"I like Regexs"
```